# sqlite database in Spark: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Following is the content in spark-defaults.conf.template file :

```
spark.master                    spark://10.10.51.93:7077
spark.driver.extraClassPath = C:/spark/spark/bin/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar
spark.executor.extraClassPath = C:/spark/spark/bin/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar
spark.jars = C:/spark/spark/bin/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.6.jar
```

Its a standalone installation and master is running on the same machine ,

Pyspark is fired from anaconda command prompt .

Following is the code in Jupyter note book :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
sqlCtx.read.format("jdbc").options(url ="jdbc:sqlite:E:/Databases/devtest.db", driver="org.sqlite.JDBC", dbtable="bin_data").load().take(10)
```

Error :

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o70.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverRegistry$.register(DriverRegistry.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions$$anonfun$6.apply(JDBCOptions.scala:79)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCOptions.<init>(JDBCOptions.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any clue how to overcome this issue

Comment: "is the content in spark-defaults.conf.template file" - if anything it should be content of `spark-defaults.conf` not `spark-defaults.conf.template`. And 3.8.6 is __very__ (2014) old.

Comment: @user8371915 these are the conf files which are of type template in the conf folder of spark

Comment: replaced the jdbc jar with latest one and still the same error persists

Comment: Just tried copying the jdbc jar file to spark\jars folder and it worked

Comment: Right. The bin folder is should only be scripts, not external libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried copying the jdbc jar file to spark\jars folder and it worked